# Executing js before AutoPostBack of checkbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, scriptmanager

NET 4 and asp checkbox which does an auto post back inside a user control and I need to call a js before that autopostback occurs.

Editing the onclick attribute of InputAttributes was of no help. It doesn't let me do that.

Tried registering on submit event or startupscript which was of no help. Unless there's a way to register on submit when checkbox was clicked or unclicked. Haven't found this yet. When I do register on submit my function gets called whenever anything happens on the page.

Don't want to start including jquery on my page just for this.

My last option would be to submit the form in js without AutoPostBack, however would love a solution using Register on submit or register startup instead of this. I want to be consistent with my code.

Thanks
-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use/override **OnPreRender(Eventargs e){}** method to process additional functionality. It registers client script for generating post-back events prior to rendering on the client, if AutoPostBack is true.

For example: You have an asp checkbox defined as

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Text="Check this box" AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

In your .cs file

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) 
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            chkBox.Attributes["onChange"] = "clickMe();";
        }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(IsPostBack){
                chkBox.Text = "After Post Back";
            }
        }
```

**clickMe()** should be defined in your .ascx file in script block.

```
function clickMe() {
            alert("SCRIPT RAN FIRST");
        }
```

Now, if you click on the checkbox, the script code will execute first and then the postback code (if you have any)
This should help.